# PHP Not Posting Data After Submit

Tags: php

I cannot figure out why my form does not want to submit its data into my recipes table after clicking submit. When I click the submit button the form just refreshes,
I have an echo for successful set but it does not appear along with no error messages and no data in my database.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="main-login main-center">
    <h1>Add Recipe</h1>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipe_name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Recipe Name</label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipe_name" id="recipe_name"  placeholder="Recipe Name"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipe_duration" class="cols-sm-2 control-label"> Recipe Duration </label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipe_duration" id="recipe_duration"  placeholder="Recipe Duration"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipe_ingredient" class="cols-sm-2 control-label"> Ingredients </label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipe_ingredient" id="recipe_ingredient"  placeholder="Ingredients"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipe_nutrition" class="cols-sm-2 control-label"> Recipe Nutrition </label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipe_nutrition" id="recipe_nutrition"  placeholder="Recipe Nutrition"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipe_method" class="cols-sm-2 control-label"> Recipe Directions </label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipe_method" id="recipe_method"  placeholder="Recipe Directions"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="profile_image">Recipe Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="recipe_image" id="recipe_image">
            <p class="help-block">Upload an image of the recipe</p>
            <img class="recipeImage" src="./recipe_images/"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

and PHP

```
                    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        //Insert DB
        $query = "INSERT INTO recipes (recipe_name, recipe_duration, recipe_ingredient, recipe_nutrition, recipe_method) VALUES (:recipe_name, :recipe_duration, :recipe_in

gredient, :recipe_nutrition, :recipe_method)";
    $result = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(':recipe_name', $_POST['recipe_name']);
    $result->bindParam(':recipe_duration', $_POST['recipe_duration']);
    $result->bindParam(':recipe_ingredient', $_POST['recipe_ingredient']);
    $result->bindParam(':recipe_nutrition', $_POST['recipe_nutrition']);
    $result->bindParam(':recipe_method', $_POST['recipe_method']);
    if($target_file){
        $result->bindParam(':recipeImage', $newFilename);
    }
    if($result->execute()){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Recipe Added!</div>';
    }

    if($_FILES['recipeImage']["name"]){
        //Let's add a random string of numbers to the start of the filename to make it unique!

        $newFilename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).$_FILES["profile_image"]["name"];
        $target_file = "./recipe_images/" . basename($newFilename);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["recipeImage"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check === false) {
            echo "File is not an image!";
            $uploadError = true;
        }

        //Check file already exists - It really, really shouldn't!
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadError = true;
        }

        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["recipeImage"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadError = true;
        }

        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadError = true;
        }

        // Did we hit an error?
        if ($uploadError) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        } else {
            //Save file
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["recipeImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                //Success!
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
}

            ?>
```

Comment: Do you have php code in same page or in another page ?

Comment: remove hash from action attribute of form.

Comment: Be3cause you have no element with `name="submit"` and you're testing for it here `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: code is in same page, tried removing # same issue, thanks for your help!

Comment: U can give the name for submit button

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button" name = "submit">Submit</button> you have missed name attribute inside button. correct it, then it will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have no element with `name="submit"` and you're testing for it here `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Your submit should be an `input`, not a `button`:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Also buttons don't have a default action so it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button">
```

change the submit button like this

Comment: Why should the OP make this change?

Comment: Because  he is checking isset($_POST['submit'] but he doesn't have any variable named as submit

Comment: Then put that in your answer, don't make the OP guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button">Submit</button>
```

instead of

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: Wrong, value doesn't matter

Comment: we have change attribute from button to input type...check first it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button">Submit</button>
```

To

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block login-button">Submit</button>
```

Actually you needed to add a name attribute to the button element, so that you can identify the element in the following php line

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

The line above checks for a "POST"ed element identified by the name  'submit'.